# How does Java Transformer use multiple xslt files

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have one XSLT file including other two xml files to generate html page, like below

```
<xsl:include href="xsltcache://UtilityTemplates.xml" />
<xsl:include href="xsltcache://eCertSpecificTemplates.xml" />
```

I do not know how to add multiple xsl sources (three files in this case) to transformer,

```
Source xslSource = new StreamSource(xslFile);
Transformer trasformToXml=tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very specialized form of URI in the xsl:include directives, these look as if they were designed to be handled by custom URI dereferencing logic, perhaps an OASIS catalog.

The bog-standard way to do this would be to use relative URIs in the `xsl:include` (for example `<xsl:include href="UtilityTemplates.xsl"/>`, to put all three files in the same directory, and then to make sure that the base URI of the main file is known (which it will be if `xslFile` is a `File` object).

If there's some special magic to the "xsltcache" URIs then you need to find out what it is. But if you don't want to change the source, you can set a `URIResolver` on the `TransformerFactory`. The `URIResolver` will be called when an `xsl:include` declaration is encountered, and it can do anything it likes to convert the supplied URI to a `Source` object containing the included module.

Comment: Thanks heaps Michael, I solved the problems by using URIResolver.