# TransformerFactory - Using multiple stylesheets

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd

I have multiple XSL's or style sheets for schematron validation of an XML (where one is the root and others being imported to the root). The below code is for one stylesheet.

```
public XMLSaxonTransformer(InputStream styleSheet) {
    final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
    try {
        styleSheetTemplate = transformerFactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(styleSheet), new StreamSource(styleSheet));
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        throw new Exception("Exception caught while parsing StyleSheet", e);
    }
}
```

The above works for single stylesheet. but, my requirement is for multiple stylesheets with one root and others being included in the root.

My code should look something like below.

```
public XMLSaxonTransformer(List<InputStream> styleSheetList) {
final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
try {

    // do something to add the XSL's list to the transformer

} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    throw new Exception("Exception caught while parsing StyleSheet", e);
}}
```

Comment: Yes, one among them is the root which includes others. but, i dont have them in local file system to give the root. All of them are given as StreamSource.

Answer (score 0):

You should only specify the top-level stylesheet to the `TransformerFactory.newTemplates()` method. The top-level stylesheet will pull in other stylesheet modules using `xsl:include` or `xsl:import`. If those stylesheet modules exist only in memory, you will need to nominate a `URIResolver` to the `TransformerFactory`. Your `URIResolver` will be called when an `xsl:include` or `xsl:import` declaration is encountered, and it should return a `Source` object (for example a `StreamSource`) to deliver the contents of the stylesheet module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865349/how-does-java-transformer-use-multiple-xslt-files
According to this, the XSL's can be pulled when it encounters xsl:import only when they are stored locally in same directory and this directory URI is set using URIResolver to the TransformerFactory.
But, i have my XSL's in S3 storage and cannot store them locally. I only have StreamSource of all the XSL's in list format with no clue about the root.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the answer to 41865349. It's a good idea to ensure that your stylesheet modules have a base URI (or "SystemId") by using the second argument of `new StreamSource()`. There is no need for this to be an actual physical directory.